# Is there any way to kill application with known package name?

Tags: android

I am using following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; i++)
ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo task = tasksP.get(i);
```

from `task.processName` I am getting process package name e.g `com.android.alarmclock` (running app)

I want to kill this application, is there anyway to do that ??

Comment: This is such a duplicate it's not even funny:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303615/how-do-task-managers-kill-apps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504091/how-to-kill-other-apps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951660/kill-an-app-package-in-api-8-froyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way of killing an application

```
/* Way one */
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())

/* Way Two */
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: None of them will work if your activity stack is not empty. Android will restart the process and spawn the topmost activity from the stack.